# add/delete object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array.

```
[  
   {  
      tab:0,
      ip:'555.222.111.555',
      stid:'sth'
   },
   {  
      tab:0,
      ip:'123.321.231.123',
      stid:'aaa'
   },
]
```

Now I need to

1. add `+1` to `tab` where `ip` is `555.222.111.555`.
2. remove whole object where `ip` is `123.321.231.123`.

Comment: It is an object... Go through `Array#splice` to do so...

Comment: And to find the object, `var found = arr.find(function(item) {
  return item.ip == '555.222.111.555';
});
++found.tab;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an array of objects not an array of arrays.

You can do something like this:

```js
var arr = [  
  {  
     tab:0,
     ip:'555.222.111.555',
     stid:'sth'
  },
  {  
     tab:0,
     ip:'123.321.231.123',
     stid:'aaa'
  },
];

for(var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(arr[i].ip === "555.222.111.555"){
        arr[i].tab++; // increment tab by 1.
    }else if(arr[i].ip === "123.321.231.123"){
        arr.splice(i,1); // delete this object.
    }
}
console.dir(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
var adresses = [
  {
    tab : 0,
    ip : '555.222.111.555',
    stid : 'sth'
  },
  {
    tab : 0,
    ip : '123.321.231.123',
    stid : 'aaa'
  }
];
var results = adresses.filter((x) => x.ip != "555.222.111.555");
results.forEach((x) => {x.tab++});
console.log(results); // [ { tab: 1, ip: '123.321.231.123', stid: 'aaa' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely try like this:

```js
var a = [{
  tab: 0,
  ip: '555.222.111.555',
  stid: 'sth'
}, {
  tab: 0,
  ip: '123.321.231.123',
  stid: 'aaa'
}];

// search the element in the existing array.
function search(ip) {
    for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      if (a[i].ip === ip) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  // adds an ip to the global storage.

function add(ip, stid) {
    debugger;
    var index = search(ip);
    if (index !== undefined) {
      a[index].tab += 1;
    } else {
      a.push({
        tab: 1,
        ip: ip,
        stid: stid
      });
    }
  }
  // remove the ip history from the storage.

function remove(ip) {
    var index = search(ip);
    if (index !== undefined) {
      a.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  // adds a tab of this ip.
add('123.321.231.123');
// removes the ip.
remove('555.222.111.555');

console.dir(a);
```

Comment: hey @Reason Please validate and let me know if you have concerns.

Comment: Im use your search function but im don't test rest of code

Comment: Great man! @Reason Just give an up vote if the part was useful. :p  And rest code was for the illustration. You can just "Run Code Snippet" to check its output.